# all possible 3 digit combinations of 1 and 0 in python

Tags: python, combinations

Is there a function to return all 3 digit combination of 1 and 0 in lists?
The desired output should look like below:

```
[0,0,0]

[1,0,0]

[0,1,0]

[0,0,1]

[1,1,0]

[1,0,1]

[0,0,1]

[1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
from itertools import product

def split_str(s):
  return [int(ch) for ch in s]

k=3
mm = []
m = ["".join(seq) for seq in product("01", repeat=k)]
mm = list(map(split_str, m))
print(mm)
```

The result is:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Other solution suggested by **Izaak van Dongen**:

```
mm2 = list(product([0, 1], repeat=3))
print(mm2)
```

Will result in the following output (that its easily can by "untupled"):

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Hello! It seems to be that this can be achieved perfectly well without messing around with strings: just take `list(product([0, 1], repeat=3))` (and convert each tuple to a list if you really want)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you, I added your solution also, very elegant 1 liner

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import `itertools`, you can do this:

```
n = 3

for i in range(0, 2**n):
    print([*map(int, '{:0{n}b}'.format(i, n=n))])
```

Prints:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You specifically asked for a "list"-output, so this answer may not help you at all.

On the other hand, you did not specify what you need it for. So if you need it for comparison, you should bee looking at another data type: [Set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).